# Simple network mask question

Tags: cisco, ipv4, subnet, ip-address, packet-tracer

I have a question about network masks.

- Host A IP : 10.0.0.1/24
- Host B IP : 10.0.0.2/25

Why is PC1 able to ping PC2, but when PC2 tries to ping PC1, it times out?  Can I get a detailed explanation?

**Edit for clarification:**

On PC1 we did `ping -c2 10.0.0.2`, and we did get a reply successfully from PC2. On PC2 we did `ping -c2 10.0.0.1`, and we did not get a reply successfully from PC1. We want to know why this happened?

[image]

**Update:** We used `10.0.0.200/25` instead, and were able to ping PC1 to PC2, but not PC2 to PC1, which is what we wanted. Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: You need to give a lot more context around this. If those two hosts are connected to the same switch, on the same VLAN. There is no reason they shouldn't be able to ping each other.

Comment: Now if host B's IP had been 10.0.0.200/25 instead, then packets would go from A to B, but they shouldn't go back, so it shouldn't ping.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: There is something else going on. As I wrote in my first comment, based on the information you have given us, and if both PCs are on a single VLAN, there is no reason the two PCs can't ping each other. You should give us more information, e.g. a diagram, switch model(s) and configurations, etc. The PCs, themselves, are off-topic here.

Comment: They are either in different layer-2 networks, or there's a firewall involved: A ping B, B answers; B pings A, A ignores it.

Comment: Update: diagram added

Comment: The problem lies in your PCs, and questions about those are off-topic here. As @RickyBeam pointed out, it is probably a firewall on one of the PCs.

Comment: Do your PCs have a firewall enabled?

Comment: We did the experiment again and were able to ping both ways

Comment: We used 10.0.0.200/25 instead and were able to ping PC1 to PC2 but not PC2 to PC1 which is what we wanted. Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the two PCs are on different networks. The PC with `10.0.0.1/24` is on a network which spans hosts `10.0.0.1` to `10.0.0.254`, while the PC with `10.0.0.200/25` is on a network with hosts from `10.0.0.129` to `10.0.0.254`, but the network doesn't include the first PC with the address `10.0.0.1`. Clearly the second host thinks the first host is on a different network.

When an IP host wants to send something to another IP host, it first looks to see if the destination IP address is on the same network as itself. If not, it sends the traffic to its configured gateway.